# Infinite do-while loop on C (2 conditions)

Tags: c, infinite-loop, do-while

In this part of my program in C the Do-While goes infinite. i was trying to make a
loop for the case that someone wanted to type a string instead of numeric value.

```
int main(){
    int cnotas;

    do{
    printf("\nIngrese la Cantidad de Notas del Estudiante\n--------------------------------------------\n");    //asks for the number of grades that are going to be used in the average calculation

    if(cnotas>=1){    //if statement to break the loop when the amount of grades is 1 or more
        break;
    }

    }while(scanf("%d", &cnotas)==0 && cnotas<1);    \\gets the cnotas value and checks if is valid
    promedioe(cnotas);
    system("pause");
}
```

Updated!

**Forget to mention that i want to reject non numeric inputs from the user, so the program doesn't crash.**

Comment: if you terminate the input stream, scanf will never read anything and it loops forever. if you type a number, it should exit

Comment: Review `if(cnotas>=1)`.  What is the value of `cnotas` the first time executed?

Comment: The execution never breaks out of the loop because the non-numeric characters stay in the input buffer and are always read by scanf immediately. You need to clear the input buffer when you get an invalid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In this statement: `while(scanf("%d", &cnotas)==0 && cnotas<1);` you are expecting no input to be entered by the user since `scanf` returns the no. of inputs successfully read. At the At the same time you are expecting the input value to be lesser than 1.
- `cnotas` is `auto` variable so its starting value may be anything, initialize it.
- Better make it: `}while(scanf(" %d",&cnotas)==1 && cnotas<1);`
- Apart from all this you have written comments with wrong tag `\\` rather than `//`.

Comment: What if scanf fails and returns negative?

Comment: @KamilCuk In condition of `EOF` the loop will simply cease.

Comment: `EOF` is `-1` on most systems and must be negative. What is scanf returns any value different than 1?

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you please explain how will that happen?

Comment: If stdin will be closed by the system after reading one input. Try: `cnotas; main() { do; while(scanf("%d", &cnotas) == 1 && cnotas < 1); printf("%d", cnotas); }` and run as `echo 3 | program` (on linux). This will properly read 3, which is greater then 1, the loop will then exit because scanf will return EOF and the program will output 3.

Comment: @KamilCuk Is it to be run like `echo 3 | ./m`?

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you want to do. You want to read input until the value read is lower then 1.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int cnotas;
    do {
         printf("\nIngrese la Cantidad de Notas del Estudiante\n--------------------------------------------\n");    //asks for the number of grades that are going to be used in the average calculation

        // Read the input...
        if (scanf("%d", &cnotas) != 1) {
              fprintf(stderr, "scanf error!\n");
              exit(-1);
        }
        // ...until the input is lower then 1    
    } while (cnotas < 1);
    promedioe(cnotas);
    system("pause");
}
```